# iOS : Other alternative to instance variable?

Tags: ios, variables, instance

I have a project which others have written and I have taken over it, hoping to make the app better.

I encountered one problem:

From one class:

I write _customclass.variable. CustomClass is another class and variable is a property and is of int type. And I get value of the variable in this class, but when I change it to self.customclass.variable, I always get 0. Is there other alternative ways to get value from other class?

(a)

```
@property (readwrite)int boxSpacing;
```

(b)

```
@synthesize boxSpacing;
```

(c)

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self.boxSpacing = 10;
}
```

Comment: Your syntax here is a little confusing because the convention is to put the leading underscore on the instance variable name, not the class name itself. You should show us (a) your `@property` declaration; (b) your `@synthesize` statement; and (c) if you explicitly declared any instance variables (which you generally shouldn't for properties, anyway), show us those.

Comment: @Rob Thanks for comment. Please see my edit, is it more clear now?

Comment: If your class isn't a singleton, it won't retain the values, through the App lifecycle, so the value will be accessible, only in the Class/ViewController you initialize the custom class in only...

Comment: @GourmetFan Ok, that's correct. As you've demonstrated, you can refer to `self.boxSpacing` without incident. But I'm not following your notion of the variable with the leading underscore. You only do that if you use `@synthesize boxSpacing = _boxSpacing` in which case you can either refer to `self.boxSpacing` or use the instance variable directly, `_boxSpacing`. (This distinction between the instance variable, `_boxSpacing` and the property, `self.boxSpacing` is only important for class objects, not for simple variables like `int` variables, but it's good to be consistent.)

Comment: @Lefteris No offense, but (a) it strikes me that the singleton discussion is not relevant and doesn't illuminate the OP's original question; (b) in terms of "retaining" values, we're dealing with a simple `int` variable, so the notion of `retain` is not relevant either; (c) if you declare a `@property` for a class, the entire purpose of that is to make that property accessible outside of the class, so any code that has access to that object (whether it created the object itself, or whether it received a reference to that object from elsewhere) will have access to that property.

Comment: Yes Rob, but that class is going to be initialized from within a certain view controller, so each view controller will create a new pointer value that it will reference, meaning that you cannot access the same variable from another view controller instance, unless it's being initialized and accessed via the App's delegate

Comment: @Rob the previous developer used underscore and drew custom scroll view in Storyboard, whereas I tried drawing custom scroll view programmatically and I tried using accessor method "self.", and I get no value if I call boxSpacing from another class. I understand that it is important to be consistent, but how do I solve this?

Comment: @Lefteris If one assumes that this is a property of a view controller and that you wouldn't pass to subsequent view controllers that you might present/push, then you're quite right. But there are plenty of cases where an app might maintain model data and pass references around, or you might have something at the app delegate, or any of a dozen different coding patterns. If all you're trying to say is that the property is only accessible within the scope of the object that has that property, then you're quite right.

Comment: @GourmetFan By the way, your `initWithCoder` method is using the setter for `boxSpacing`, but as a matter of good style, [you should use the instance variable](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004447-SW6) in initializer methods (though you should use the accessor methods elsewhere). Also, I also assume you've omitted the bulk of `initWithCoder` for reasons of brevity, because you're missing the bulk of the initializer. See my answer below for more thoughts on the substance of your question.

Answer (score 3):

You asked:

> Is there other alternative ways to get value from other class?

The short answer is that using the "getter" is the customary way to get a value from another class. But looking at your problem (admitted, not having enough source code to properly diagnose your issue), I'm guessing that the issue rests in the use of instance variables. But more on that later.

First, let's look at the proper use of [declared properties](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/chapters/ocproperties.html) and their instance variables and their accessor methods (the getters and setters). [Generally you should set properties using these accessor methods.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004447-SW5) You can, though, use access a variable from within a class using either the instance variable (and you [should not use accessor methods in initializer and dealloc methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004447-SW6)). And when using the getter and setter, you can choose whether to use the method invocation (e.g. "`[self customObject]`") or the dot notation (e.g. "`self.customObject`").

Let's look at an example. Let's assume you have some simple `CustomClass`:

```
@interface CustomClass : NSObject
{
    // you don't need to declare the instance variable

    //int _boxSpacing;
}

@property (nonatomic) int boxSpacing;

@end

@implementation CustomClass

// In Xcode 4.4 and later, the synthesize statement is optional, and if you
// omit it, it will synthesize the instance variable like this, with the 
// leading underscore. While you don't need to use an underscore in your
// instance variable, it has become convention in iOS development and it's
// a good technique to minimize chances that you accidentally use the instance
// variable when you actual intended to use the property's accessor methods 
// (the getter and setter). 

@synthesize boxSpacing = _boxSpacing;

@end
```

Now, let's assume that you're going to use this `CustomClass` from within, for example, your view controller. So, first you declare and instance of this `CustomClass`:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController
{
    // you do not need this instance variable declaration
    // the @synthesize statement will take care of this for you

    // CustomClass *_customObject;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) CustomClass *customObject;

@end
```

And then let's demonstrate how to use the `value` property of the `CustomClass` object `customObject` from within your view controller:

```
@implementation MyViewController

// Again, in Xcode 4.4 and later, the synthesize statement is optional, and if you
// omit it, it will synthesize the instance variable like this, with the 
// leading underscore 

@synthesize customObject = _customObject;

- (void)customClassTest
{
    // initialize the object

    self.customObject = [[CustomClass alloc] init];

    // set the property

    self.customObject.boxSpacing = 1;

    // finally, let's demonstrate three ways to retrieve the value

    NSLog(@"%d", self.customObject.boxSpacing);
    NSLog(@"%d", [[self customObject] boxSpacing]);
    NSLog(@"%d", _customObject.boxSpacing);

    // while we're at it, let's demonstrate other ways to set the property

    _customObject.boxSpacing = 2;

    // or

    [[self customObject] setBoxSpacing:3];
}
```

Ok, so let's get back to your problem. You say:

> I write _customclass.variable. CustomClass is another class and variable is a property and is of int type. And I get value of the variable in this class, but when I change it to self.customclass.variable, I always get 0.

Ok, this can be caused by a couple of different problems, but the most common problem I see is confusion between explicitly declared instance variables and the instance variables created behind the scenes by the `@synthesize` statement. This is why I always advise that people not explicitly define the instance variables for their declared properties, but rather let the `@synthesize` statement do that automatically. That way I can't have the sort of problem I'm about to demonstrate.

Consider this innocuous (though incorrect) example:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController
{
    CustomClass *_customObject;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) CustomClass *customObject;

@end

@implementation MyViewController

@synthesize customObject;

- (void)customClassTestError
{
    // initialize the object

    self.customObject = [[CustomClass alloc] init];

    // this works

    self.customObject.boxSpacing = 1;

    // this doesn't!

    _customObject.boxSpacing = 2;

    // when it hits this statement, the value will still be 1!!!

    NSLog(@"%d", self.customObject.boxSpacing);
}
```

Do you see the problem? While I declared an instance variable with the underscore, `_customObject`, when the compiler hit the `@synthesize` statement, it created *another* instance variable, this time without the leading underscore, `customObject`. Thus, my explicitly declared instance variable never received the init/alloc and therefore is `nil` and thus any attempts to use it won't work!

Typically we see the converse problem (an explicitly declared instance variable without the underscore and a `@synthesize` statement of the form `@synthesize customObject = _customObject`), but hopefully you'll get the idea.

Anyway, this is the most common example of what would cause the behavior you describe. If this isn't what's going on, please provide us a more extensive code sample.

But if you're having problems, I'd always suggest that you check the value of your `CustomClass` object, itself, before you try to access its properties. Make sure the class object itself has been properly initialized (whether for the reasons I list above, or some other initialization problem) before you try to use its properties. You can do something like `NSLog(@"CustomClass object = %@", customObject);` or `NSAssert(customObject, @"Object not properly initialized");`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined a @property for the CustomClass? If so, have you assigned a value?

If not, then you're sending the message `variable` to `nil`. And in your case that will result to 0.

Comment: I have defined it as readwrite and assigned it a value of 10 in `- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {` method. The custom class is of class UIScrollView.

Comment: but have you also assigned an instance of UIScrollView to the @property of the CustomClass? Did you, for instance, hook it up in IB?

Comment: yes: `@property (unsafe_unretained, nonatomic) CustomScrollView *scrollView;` and I synthesized it in .m like this `@synthesize scrollView = _scrollView;` I make everything programmatically, so no need for IB in this case.

Comment: so you assign an instance of CustomScrollView to the property somewhere? `self.scrollView = [[CustomScrollView alloc] init]` for instance?

Comment: `[[CustomScrollView alloc]initWithFrame: frame];` That is correct. In loadView method.