# Alloc/init'ing a readonly property

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have declared in the .h class

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) SomeClass *sup;
```

In the init in the .m class, I can say

```
_sup = [[SomeClass alloc] init];
```

but not

```
self.sup = [[SomeClass alloc] init];
```

This is because it's read-only. What's the difference?

Comment: Along with plenty of others: [Difference between self and normal variable](http://stackoverflow.com/q/536388/), [Properties and accessors](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6085080/), [Ivar property, access via self?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4088801/), [When to access properties with self](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4271657/), [What is the (style) difference between “self.foo” and “foo” when using synthesized getters?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3494157/), [Difference between calling self.var vs var](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4627646), [&c.](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bobjc%5D+self.ivar)

Comment: This is not done simply because the public interface of `sup` was `readonly` (because you could/would define a private non-`readonly` interface in the private class extension, thus letting you use setter privately while keeping object `readonly` for external purposes). In reality, the reason you use `_sup` has less to do with the lack of a setter than it does with the fact that it's discouraged to use accessor methods within `init` method. Even if `sup` was originally defined as non-`readonly`, you still would not use `self.sup = ...` in init.

Comment: See [Don’t Use Accessor Methods in Initializer Methods and dealloc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004447-SW6) in the _Practical Memory Management_ section of the _Advanced Memory Management Programming Guide._

Comment: In the spirit of Josh's attempt to enumerate existing duplicate questions, I might direct you, instead, to [Best practice on using @property ivars](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12752946/best-practice-on-using-property-ivars) or [What is the correct way of init iVar variables in presence of ARC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12035149/what-is-the-correct-way-of-init-ivar-variables-in-presence-of-arc/) or [iOS : Other alternative to instance variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12529833/ios-other-alternative-to-instance-variable/).

Answer (score 3):

When you are using `_sup`, you are accessing the variable behind that property directly. When you say `self.sup` you are accessing it through the setter method, which you cannot do, since it is `readonly`. Read more about properties [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html).

Answer (score 0):

Readonly means setter method is not created. So, once you are access it through self.sup, it means you are calling a method which is not created.

_sup is a variable access only.